# Share user table from WP with Drupal

Tags: users, login, user-access

I'm developing a sister website to a well-established private site that is already built in Wordpress. I can't use Wordpress to create what I need and I am therefore using Drupal. The owners of the Wordpress site do not want their users to have to go through a separate login process to get into the Drupal site and would like their users to be able to click a link to the Drupal site and automatically be logged into the Drupal site, based on their Wordpress credentials.

I know this must be possible, but where should I start, what do I need to know/learn in order to do this?